# Difference between an IPv6 DNS and IPv4 DNS Server

Tags: networking, router, dns

I am configuring Adguard DNS on a router and was wondering what the difference is between configuring it with an IPv4 and IPv6 DNS server. If there is no difference why is there an option for either IPv4 or IPv6?

I searched the internet for resource regarding this and could not find any useful.

Answer (score 0):

Adguard DNS server will check the domain you want to visit against their blacklist servers to block advertisements.

If you install the Adguard DNS IPv4 servers, it does so through their IPv4 servers, whereas with IPv6 it does so with their IPv6 servers.

Why you need one over the other? If your ISP only gives either (only IPv4 or IPv6), not both, you need one or the other (same as what your ISP gives, should also be the service you want to use), otherwise it won't work. If your WAN is both IPv4 and IPv6, then you can use either. IPv6 is what many ISP's switch to, so it is safe to say, IPv6 if available to you, would be a good choice over IPv4.